# WinSCP client for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, scp

Are there any GUI clients for Ubuntu which can remotely connect to another Linux box over SCP?

I heard about the `fish://` protocol and Konqueror (which is for Kubuntu using KDE), but I am looking for a simple GUI SCP application for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are used to **WinSCP**,
one option is to [install **WINE**](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb) and use [WinSCP](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8552&iTestingId=14943) itself.

(note: my link is just a reference -- you may want to get the stable WINE release,
*If the latest stable release of Wine (currently Wine 1.0.1) works for you,

then you may not want to use these beta packages*).

---

I guess you are referring to [this kind of discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-47350.html) in your question.
That thread too refers WINE as one of the options (with some notes on crashes in 2007).

At the end is this **Nautilus** reference,

> Ubuntu's Nautilus file explorer works just fine.
>   Places->Connect to Server and select SSH.

That is probably what `Martin` refers in his answer.

---

Update: for the record, this answer was accepted because it indirectly referred [`SecPanel`](http://themediahost.de/secpanel/).

> **SecPanel**: SSH GUI for Unix.
>   SecPanel sits on top of SSH software-suites and supports the SSH.com and the OpenSSH-version.

Comment: This is interesting... the OP accepts this answer but someone votes it down. Would have helped to know why.

Comment: Probably since wine is not the best solution here, wine will hide a lot of the file system from the windows application and that will probably annoy most people. Wine is a emergency solution if all else fails. (Wine is great for games and that kind of stuff, but not for filesystem/network programs).

Comment: I know someone who uses wine for Microsoft Outlook too... to each their own. It would have helped more if the down-vote had noted that detail anyways.

Comment: In fact, I am not sure if the OP used the Wine answer or found the cumulative notes in this answer useful.

Comment: I have not voted for WINE solution , the discussion link which he pointed. It has lot of discussions and found SecPanel for my need.

Answer (score 16):

Since you're trying to use scp I assume there is a an SSH server running on the remote machine. You can directly connect to ssh servers using Nautilus file manager. Just use something like

> ssh://username@server:/path/on/remote/machine

in the address bar.

Furthermore, if an SSH server is running you could also use the SFTP protocol for remote file manipulation. Since Ubuntu comes with pre-installed Firefox, the easiest GUI would be the [FireFTP-plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/684).

Comment: Maybe you should translate those German words in the path.

Comment: To browse for file inside nautilus, simply use sftp instead of ssh in the adress bar, so something like sftp://username@server:/path/on/remote/machine

Comment: Just open Nautilus, press Ctrl+L and type `sftp://...`

Answer (score 11):

You can use FileZilla on Ubuntu:

```
sudo aptitude install filezilla
```

Just make sure you connect using SFTP.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the top-left corner you have three menus. Select the middle one, and then the entry named something like "Connect to server". Here you'll have a list of available methods, select SSH or SFTP and fill in the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not ask for the private key file.

Comment: @mklhmnn: It should: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1443983

Comment: I'm 100% sure that Nautilus on my Ubuntu 10.4 does NOT ask for the private key file. Maybe it expects it at some location, but it does NOT ask. I don't want to use command line to tell Nautilus the private key file - that's why I want to use a **GUI** SSH client.

Comment: I have just tried — it doesn't *ask* for private keys, it just *uses* them (the same set of keys which `ssh` cmdline client or `ssh-agent` or seahorse would use; it resides in `~/.ssh/`).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with [bareFTP](http://www.bareftp.org/) - it is in the Ubuntu repository.

bareFTP works very well. It is better than FileZilla, because for the same server and task, as SFTP-client, this cannot establish the connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Krusader](http://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2008/02/24/krusader-linux-ftpsftpscp-gui/).

> Krusader is a very powerful commander style GUI file manager for KDE
>   and many other desktop managers such as GNOME.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sshfs`.

```
~$ mkdir tmp

~$ sshfs toto@lecole.fr:Document/Blagues tmp
```

This will mount the remote `Blagues` directory to the local `tmp` directory. Then you can use a regular file browser to go into the remote directory through the local one.

To unmount the directory (make sure that no application is accesing tmp directory or files),

```
~$ fusermount -u tmp
```

Comment: Your approach would work for the command line/shell, but the user is asking for a GUI solution. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 1):

To run WinSCP under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), follow these steps:

1) sudo apt-get install wine (run this one time only, to get 'wine' in your system, if you haven't it)

2) download "Portable executable" from https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

3) make a folder and put the content of zip file in this folder

4) open a terminal

5) type "sudo su"

6) type "wine WinSCP.exe"

Done! WinSCP will run like in Windows environment!

Best regards.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be running it was root.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard about fish:// protocol and
>   konqueror(which is for Kubuntu using
>   KDE)

There is no problem using kde apps when you run gnome and the other way around.

So if you like the idea with konqueror and fish:// then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [KSSH](http://kssh.sourceforge.net/) will be useful?

I think you can install KSSH without having KDE installed - `apt-get` will just download some needed KDE libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just read about this and is very simple. In Nautilus you must go to Connect to server and at address dialog use

ssh://user@server to acces to files via SSH/SCP

ftp://user@server for ftp accesss

sftp://user@server for sftp

smb://server for windows shares