# WinSCP equivalent for Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, sync, winscp

I'm shifting most of my projects to a Linux machine, and one of the things that I miss is WinSCP. I've found other answers saying that nautilus, FileZilla etc. can be used for SFTP, but something that I loved about WinSCP was that it has two panes (FileZilla's got that) and I could start synchronization from any directory. Unison or Rsync could work, but I'd have to create a folder pair every time I want to sync two folders. Is there an SFTP client for Linux that has a two-paned view and allows ad-hoc synchronization?

Comment: Possible Duplicate -> http://superuser.com/questions/40999/winscp-ubuntu-client

Answer (score 1):

I use [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) for this, together with the [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I've been using SSHFS; in fact, currently, I'm using Unison with SSHFS (for some reason, setting remote directory wasn't working). I tried Midnight Commander, but also found Gnome Commander, and Gnome Commander seemed more similar to WinSCP. It (gnome-commander) does have a "synchronize" button, but it wasn't doing anything. will look around for solutions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KDE's Konqueror with the fish protocol (to go over ssh) or with sftp directly.

Just interact with it like it was a web browser

fish://username@server:/home/username and your good to go.

You can read more here (specifically #2):
http://www.tuxradar.com/content/20-all-new-tips-kde-42

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Commander uses meld dir syncing - please install it to get the full functionality

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and need, and got a perfectly working response, thanks to stackoverflow - here it goes -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377911/connecting-to-my-ubuntu-aws-instance-using-a-gui-interface

In Summary, the solution is to have a .ssh/config file, with following contents -

```
Host {alias}
HostName {hostname or IP address}
User {username to log in with}
IdentityFile {path to abcd.pem}
```

thanks to [femi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691688/femi)